# how to "find" a slice (byte[]) within a larger bytearray

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, arrays, nearest-neighbor

My array is made out of a bitmap so every 4th byte is 255.

In this example I have made a byte Array as in my bitmap format.. as best as I could, it's a 64 elements array.

Or in C# I could just say:

```
byte[] MyBitmapToByteArray = new byte[64];
```

and for this question, I made this Bitmap diagram as close to real as I could imagine.

[image]

If for example I need to check whether the larger one(64) contains a smaller sequence of bytes.

So on 3rd Column and Second Row the value will be:

{21, 21, 21, 255}

{31, 31, 31, 255}

{22, 22, 22, 255}

{32, 32, 32, 255}

as clear as I can ask:

the coordinates and Size of this portion/slice  within this "screen" is:
actually, an Image that could be found (on this diagram) 
at `Point(X=2, Y=1), Size.Width = 2, Size.Height = 2`

How can I "search" for the pattern found at this Point within the whole array?

The big 64 length array will look somthing like:

- 1, 2, 3, 255, 1, 2, 3, 255, 1, 2, 3, 255, 1, 2, 3, 255,...etc'

and the portion is

- 21, 21, 21, 255, 31, 31, 31, 255, 22, 22, 22, 255, 32, 32, 32, 255

and i might want to load the processing of the method in question  via parallel invoke or parallel Foreach/For  if it's possible  only if you think it may perform better.

Comment: Can we assume that there's some way to know the shape of the search bytes? Here the example says 2x2, but it seems like the 4 quads specified might just as easily be 4x1 or 1x4.

Comment: @devgeezer OK lets just say we want to look for 2X2 for the simplicity and 3x2 which will enlighten me even deeper how would it look as a starter ... then we shall try further maybe turn it into a parallel implementation too.. but lets just start from base if we don't really know the 3rd or top floor...

Comment: @devgeezer actually we can pass it as a parameter. cause when the method(find pattern/array within an array) is called it's done via reference of original bitmap taken e.g. size (w,h) Point (x,y) <--was saved as a referencing file containing : x, y, w, h then a name too. so it's all known in advance